# incomplete []byte with net.conn.Read()

Tags: go

I am coding a socket web with `Golang`, I want to send data in client with goroutine and read data in server with goroutine too.
part of my code:

client:

```
    buf := bufio.NewReader(file)
    var toWrite [][]byte
    for {
        w, _, end := buf.ReadLine()
        if end == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        toWrite = append(toWrite, w)
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(toWrite))

    for _, word := range toWrite {
        w := word

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            conn.Write(append(w, byte('\n')))
            log.Info(string(w), "\n")
        }()

    }
    wg.Wait()
```

server:

```
    for {
        conn, err := listen.Accept()
        defer conn.Close()

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("accept err: ", err)
            break
        }
        go func() {
            data := make([]byte, 1024)
            for {
                _, err := conn.Read(data)
                if err != nil {
                    break
                }
                log.Info(string(data))
            }
        }()
    }
```

However, when I run them in my terminal, sometimes it shows some incomplete words

```
INFO[2019-10-15T23:36:11+08:00] increased
based
Up
p       // no "p" in my file
Up
Up
Up
Up

Up
Up
Up
Up
Up
Up
Up
```

(there is a lot of "Up" in the file I opened in client)
is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Which side is that output coming from, client or server?

Comment: The application logs all of `data`, even though `conn.Read(data)` may have only filled part of `data`.  Use the length returned from the call to conn.Read.

Comment: You are ignoring the number of bytes read. That's required to use a network connection correctly. You are also writing each line concurrently for no reason, and it's possible you could start interleaving writes.

Answer (score 0):

The conn.read() returns the numner of bytes it was actually able to read in. What you get back from the read() depends a lot of multiple factors including tcp buffers, etc. If you want to print out formatted text, you need to read in until a '\n', and then go on to read the next line. TCP provides a continuous stream of data from the peer end. You need to fins out a way to read the correct bytes, and the correct number of them.